# The time frame for "have"

Tags: verbs, tense

> I have this red pen.

Does this mean the red pen is with me at this moment, from last week, from last month, since I was born, or just at this moment?

> I have eaten.

Does this give information about the last time I had food, or about me having had food since my childhood?

Comment: It think this is answered comprehensively at EL&U: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another

Comment: another link:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91122/how-many-tenses-are-there-in-english?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I have this pen." doesn't say since when you have that pen; it just says you have/own that pen at the moment you are saying it.

"I have eaten." says you recently had food; it is not something you say when, for example, you have not eaten anything for a week or more. For example, if somebody asks you "Did you have dinner?" you could answer "I have eaten." but that would not mean "No, I didn't have dinner; I have not eaten since a week ago."

Comment: Yes, but note that "I have this pen" doesn't necessarily mean you have the pen *with you at time of speaking*. It might just mean you *own* it, but you left it somewhere else.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. _I have_ doesn't necessarily mean "I have it with me." in the same way "I have a car like this." doesn't necessarily imply my car is somewhere close to me.